# Find the value of $\lim_{x\to 2}[(1+{5^{(x-2)}}^{-1})^{-1}]$

Tags: limits

Find $\lim_{x\to 2}[(1+{5^{(x-2)}}^{-1})^{-1}]$ where [.] represent greatest integer function

My approach is as follow
Right hand limit

$\lim_{h\to 0}[(1+{5^{(h)}}^{-1})^{-1}]$= [1/2]=0

My approach is as follow
Left hand limit

$\lim_{h\to 0}[(1+{5^{(-h)}}^{-1})^{-1}]$= [1/2]=0

My answer is zero but actual answer is limit does not exist. Where I am making mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you're getting the $\frac12$ in your computations.

$$\lim_{x\to2+}\left\lfloor\frac1{1+5^{1/(x-2)}}\right\rfloor=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\lfloor\frac1{1+5^x}\right\rfloor=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to21}\left\lfloor\frac1{1+5^{1/(x-2)}}\right\rfloor=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left\lfloor\frac1{1+5^{-x}}\right\rfloor=0$$

I suspect that the error the author made was in the second calculation, putting $\lim_{x\to\infty}5^{-x}=0$ and getting the answer $1$.  But when $x$ gets large and $5^{-x}$ small, we still have $5^{-x}>0$, so the denominator is greater than $1$, the fraction is less than $1$, and the floor function gives $0$.  There isn't some kind of "jump discontinuity at $\infty.$"